# Failed to convert serial date numbers to the right date

Tags: r, date

I read in a list of numerics from a csv file. It includes numerics like `731961,731962,731966,731967,731968` and they should correspond to `2004-01-15,2004-01-16,2004-01-20,2004-01-21,2004-01-22`.

However, when I tried to convert the numerics in R, the resulting dates were wrong, for instance, `as.Date(731961,origin="1900-01-01")  --> "3904-01-17"`.

What did I do wrong here ?

Comment: `as.Date` with an integer gives the number of days from the specified origin. 731+ thousand days from 1900 is about 2000 years.

Comment: Try origin="0-01-01".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comments, the issue is that the date origin is incorrect. You can see that if you calculate the dates, and see how far off they are:

```
inDates <- c(731961,731962,731966,731967,731968)
correctDates <- as.Date(c("2004-01-15","2004-01-16","2004-01-20","2004-01-21","2004-01-22"))

wrongDates <- as.Date(inDates, origin = "1900-01-01")

difftime(wrongDates, correctDates, units = "days")
```

They are off by 693,962 days from the correct date, suggesting that the origin is incorrect. Setting the origin to `0-01-01` as @Haboryme suggested gets close, but is still off by one day. My guess is either there is a leap-day error or that the serial numbers wanted January 1st of year 0 to be 1 instead of 0. I can't get the origin to set to a BCE date (there is probably a way, but when I found a work around, I seized it). So, I am subtracting one from the input dates, and setting the origin

```
as.Date(inDates - 1, origin = "0000/01/01")
```

However, this also suggests an alternative. If you have serial numbered dates like this routinely, and the origin changes, playing around to find the origin is a pain in the rear end. However, if you know some of the dates, and can confirm that they all use the same origin, you can subtract the `offBy` from above from each new input to get the correct dates (as long as you use the same origin).

```
as.Date(inDates - as.numeric(offBy[1]), origin = "1900-01-01")
```

Gives the correct dates as well.